# MutableState value not getting updated in Observer block

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, mutablestateof

I have a live data that I am observing in my fragment, in which I have to act on the result received from LiveData and update my MutableState which is used in a composable.

I am not able to figure out why the MutableState value is not getting changed.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
 viewModel.urlLiveData.observe(
    this@MyFragment as LifecycleOwner
  ) {
    val url = if (!it.isNullOrEmpty()) {
      //perform operations on the string received from live data (it)
    } else if (!someVariable.isNullOrEmpty()) {
      someVariable
      } else null

    url?.let { finalUrl ->
      Log.d("LOG_TAG", "url1: ${finalUrl}")
      urlMutableState.value = UrlMutableState(url = finalUrl)
      Log.d("LOG_TAG", "url2: ${urlMutableState?.value?.url}")
      
    }
  }
```

The logcat shows different URLs for url1 and url2 logs. Ideally, it must be same as I am assigning my MutableState a new value.

Here are the logs:

```
 D/LOG_TAG: url1: javascript:myCallback( )
 D/LOG_TAG: url2: https://someUrl.com/page1
```

Here, url2 holds the old value of mutableState instead of the new value.

Comment: Could you post your ViewModel where you emit this LiveData?

Comment: There are many occurrences of it, but we are emitting data like this:    urlLiveData.postValue("somevalue")

Comment: There's a problem with the thing you are posting, that's why I'd like to see the `viewModel` because theres a problem when parsing something because the first value you get is not an url

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS You want to check the initial value of urlLiveData? Well, that's an empty string

Comment: Not the empty but all the flow and where you emit the data, because it's weird you emit 2 different strings

Comment: Where did I emit two different strings? My logic is that in case the live data emits an empty string, I need to take the value of url from some another variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248411/discussion-between-ali-waris-and-skizo-oziks).